# How can I remove an object (based on it's id) from an array in a mongoose/mongoDB model?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I have a User schema in my app.  User contains a favorites key that contains an array of objects.  Each of these objects has a unique id.  I am trying to remove one of these objects based on it's id.  Here is the code that I think should work:

```
User.updateOne({id: req.user.id}, {$pull: {favorites: {id: req.params.id}}})
```

What I think should happen above is that it finds the user with the id = req.user.id, then it should be pulling the object within favorite that contains the id = req.params.id.  When I run this piece of code I don't get any errors, but it does not remove the object from the array.

I've seen many other questions asked like this, but I've tried all of their solutions.  I must be missing something!  Help!

Comment: Mongoose *"sometimes"* aliases `id` with `_id`, but this is not consistent. I suggest using `_id` when you really mean it, and moreover to not create your own field of `id`  since mongoose will *"generally"* attempt to use this as an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query

```
   const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
   User.updateOne({id: ObjectId(req.user.id)}, {$pull: {favorites: {id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}}})
```

Comment: This did not work.  I also don't think I need to create any new ids, as my User schema has an id (accessed by req.user.id), and each favorite object already has an id.

Comment: Please share collection